# Using the power series method to solve $y''-(1+x)y'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am trying to solve the following second order differential equation.
$$y''-(1+x)y'-y=0$$
I believe this differential equation can be solved using the power series method. So, suppose $y(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k$. Substitution into the differential equation gives,
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{k\geq 2}a_kk(k-1)x^{k-2}-(1+x)\sum_{k\geq 1}a_kkx^{k-1}-\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k=0\\
\sum_{k\geq 2}a_kk(k-1)x^{k-2}-\sum_{k\geq 1}a_kkx^{k-1}-\sum_{k\geq 1}a_kkx^{k}-\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k=0\\
\sum_{k\geq 0}a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)x^{k}-\sum_{k\geq 0}a_{k+1}(k+1)x^{k}-\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kkx^{k}-\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k=0\\
\sum_{k\geq 0}\left[a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)-a_{k+1}(k+1)-a_kk-a_k\right] x^k=0
\end{gather*}
Hence we must have
$$a_{k+2}(k+2)(k+1)-a_{k+1}(k+1)-a_kk-a_k=0\text{ for all } k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$$
In other words,
$$a_{k+2}=\frac{a_{k+1}(k+1)+a_k(k+1)}{(k+2)(k+1)}$$
for all $k\geq 0$.

I am stuck on finding the pattern for these coefficients. The answer is $y(x)=e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$ but I do not see how they got to that. Is there a simple way/explanation that will lead me to $e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$?

EDIT: Trying out the approach mentioned in the comments
$$y''(x)-(1+x)y'(x)-y(x)=0$$
Using the observation $-((1+x)y(x))'=-y(x)-(1+x)y'(x)$ we get
$$y''(x)-((1+x)y(x))'=0$$
$$\left[y'(x)-(1+x)y(x)\right]'=0$$
Now integrating both sides with respect to $x$ gives
$$\int \left[y'(x)-(1+x)y(x)\right]'\,dx=\int 0\,dx$$
$$y'(x)-(1+x)y(x)=C$$
Let $I(x)=e^{\int -(1+x)dx}=e^{-\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}$ be the integrating factor. Multiplying both sides by $I(x)$ gives
$$I(x)y'(x)-I(x)(1+x)y(x)=I(x)C$$
$$(I(x)y(x))'=I(x)C$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $x$ yields
$$\int (I(x)y(x))'\,dx=\int I(x)C \,dx$$
$$I(x)y(x)=\int I(x)C \,dx$$
$$y(x)=\frac{C}{I(x)}\int I(x)\,dx$$
$$y(x)=C_1e^{\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\left(\int e^{-\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\,dx+C_2\right)$$
Now $y(0)=1$ gives
$$1=C_1\left(\int 1\,dx+C_2\right)$$
$$1=C_1\cdot C_2$$
Now $y(1)=1$ gives
$$1=C_1e^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(\int e^{-\frac{3}{2}}\,dx+C_2\right)$$
$$1=C_1e^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(e^{-\frac{3}{2}}+C_2\right)$$
$$1=C_1+C_1C_2$$
From the first equation we get $C_1=\frac{1}{C_2}$. Hence,
$$1=\frac{1}{C_2}\frac{1}{C_2}C_2=\frac{1}{C_2}+1$$
$$C_2=1+C_2$$
$$0=1$$

Comment: There is a way to solve this analytically. Use the reverse product rule on the two terms lesser order terms (not the y''), factor out the derivative, integrate, and then use integrating factor method to complete the solution.

Comment: $k\neq-1$ so the factors of $k+1$ can be removed.

Comment: @user170231 thank you that simplifies some things.

Comment: @Max0815 I think I used the reverse product rule you mentioned and got $y''-((1+x)y)'=0$. I don't think I follow what you mean by factor out the derivative. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: $y''-((1+x)y)'= (y'-(1+x)y)'=0 \Rightarrow y'-(1+x)y=C_1$ is first order ODE you can solve it with integrating factor $\mu = e^{\int -(1+x)dx} = e^{-(x+\frac{x^2}{2})}$. for exact form of solution you need to provide initial values! even for power series approach.

Comment: Wow, I see now! Yes, the initial conditions are $y(0)=1,y(1)=1$ which I can use to finish off the problem now. Thank you.

Comment: @AbolfazlChamanmotlagh I have edited my post above to include the work for the approach we discussed here in the comments. I was unable to use the initial values to find the unknown constants. I believe I need to find $\int e^{-(x+\frac{x^2}{2})}$ to solve for the constants, correct? And that does not have an elementary antidertivitve. I don't quite see how the final answer will be $y(x)=e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as from the comments I will solve this the analytical way. I had not answered since your question had asked for a power series approach (which i was too lazy to try lol) but from my understanding since you just want a way to solve the diffeq, I will provide this method.

So we have $$y''-(1+x)y'-y=0\Longleftrightarrow y''+(-1-x)y'+(-1-x)'y=0$$
$$\implies y'' + ((-1-x)y)'=0$$
via the reverse product rule.

Since the derivative is a linear operation, we can factor this out as follows
$$ y'' + ((-1-x)y)'=0\Longleftrightarrow(y'+(-1-x)y)'=0$$
Integrating both sides w.r.t. $x$ yields the first order diffeq
$$y'+{\color{red}{(-1-x)}}y=C$$ for some constant $C$.

Our integrating factor is $\displaystyle \exp\left(\int{\color{red}{-1-x}}\text{ d}x\right) = e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x+A}$ but we choose $A=0$, so our integrating factor becomes $e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}$.

Multiplying both sides by the integrating factor gives
$$e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}y'+e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}(-1-x)y=Ce^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}\Longleftrightarrow e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}y'+\left(e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}\right)'y=Ce^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}$$
$$\implies \left(ye^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}\right)'=Ce^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}$$
Integrating both sides gives us
$$ye^{-\frac{x^2}2-x} = C\int e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}\text{ d}x$$
We will solve the integral as follows. If we complete the square on $-\frac{x^2}2-x$, we get $-\frac12(x+1)^2+\frac12$.
$$\implies C\int e^{-\frac{x^2}2-x}\text{ d}x = C\int e^{-\frac12(x+1)^2+\frac12}\text{ d}x = Ce^{1\over2}\int e^{-\frac12(x+1)^2}\text{ d}x$$
Use the change of variables $u=x+1$ and $v=\frac{u}{\sqrt2}$ to get
$$\implies Ce^{1\over2}\int e^{-\frac12u^2}\text{ d}u$$
$$\implies C\sqrt2 e^{1\over2}\int e^{-v^2}\text{ d}v = C\sqrt2 e^{1\over2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\int \frac2{\sqrt\pi} e^{-v^2}\text{ d}v = C\sqrt2 e^{1\over2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}(v)+K$$
$$\implies C\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+K$$
We have used the definition of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) to get this result. Here, $K$ and $C$ are two arbitrary constants.

Now, we solve for $y$ to get the general solution of $$y = Ce^{\frac{x^2}2+x}\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+Ke^{\frac{x^2}2+x}$$

To reduce this solution down to the specific one in your IVP with $y(0)=1,y(1)=1$, we simply substitute in these values and solve for the constants in the resulting system of equations. However, something is wrong with the initial values you provided, as they do not return your solution $y(x)=e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$. You can check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27-%281%2Bx%29y%27-y%3D0%2C%20y%280%29%3D1%2C%20y%281%29%3D1).

We can, however, see through inspection that for
$$y = Ce^{\frac{x^2}2+x}\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}2}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+Ke^{\frac{x^2}2+x}\equiv y(x)=e^{x+\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
we must have it such that $C=0$ and $K=1$. Once you get the right initial values solving for these constants should be trivial.

Edit:
Yep, from your new given initial values $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=1$, this indeed gives the correct constants. (For the derivative of the error function when taking the product rule just apply the definition again)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. I am not familiar with the error function. In what type of courses does a student learn of this function? Do you have any resources that will act as a good introduction on this type of function?

Comment: Also, as you pointed out, I accidentally gave the wrong initial conditions. The correct ones are $y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$ and they do indeed give the expected result.

Comment: @Moh Yep no problem. Well for me personally, I first discovered the error function after taking calc BC, and finding that some integrals like the gaussian $\int e^{-x^2}\text{ d}x$ were not integrable in elementary functions. This led me down into a rabbit-hole of researching about it and other special functions. In practice tho (like for me this year xd), you will learn about the error function in a typical statistics class, since the gaussian is the equation for a normal curve, and you need to integrate that to get probabilities

Comment: @Moh In the future, if you ever encounter an integral with an integrand of $\exp(\text{quadratic})$, you want to try to convert it into an error function form as found in the definition in wikipedia. Honestly though there isn't much to learn about the error function in the integration sense, just know how to apply its definition to some integrals. If you take a statistics course though you probability will learn a lot more on its properties and use it a lot more lol

Comment: I see, thank you for the information.